# Use multiple value files on helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I got into a scenario where I need to create a deployment template to use multiple value files one after the another without merging or overriding.
The valueFiles as specified in argoCD application yaml file under valueFiles parameter.

Can someone help on how to overcome this situation. I need to create a helm template which should take value file one after another using some range function or so.

Thanks in advance

A simple helm template example to use pass multiple value files one after another to a helm template.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for that's different from using multiple `helm install -f` options, or multiple `helm install` runs with different release names and a single `-f` option each?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello … I did try -f option for specifying multiple value files but it generally overrides the value file contents. But I want to run all the value files one after another in a loop on the helm template without getting overrided or merged

Comment: Can you run `helm install` multiple times?  Would that have the effect you want?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass 2 values files to your ARGOCD app. Some reference docs [here](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/user-guide/helm/#values-files).

example:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: argo-workflows
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
  labels:
    cluster: dev
spec:
  project: foo

  source: 
    repoURL: https://github.io/myorganization/myrepo'
    targetRevision: master
    helm:
      valueFiles:
        - values.yaml # the main values file
        - some-extra-values-file.yaml # this is your extra values file
    repoURL: 'https://github.io/myorganization/myrepo'
    targetRevision: master
```

...
It is also important to make sure content in 1st file does not occur in 2nd values file to be overwritten in the conflict. It would make logical sense to me to just do it in one file, but I guess everyone has uniquely interesting and different problem context.

I don't know if my answer to this problem is correct, but you can also check helm dependancies. This can also be related to what you are trying to achieve, just a guess. Link [here](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/).